# How to merge two trained models into a new model having the same input. (Tensorflow 2.x)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I have trained two CNN models separately and saved their weights in h5 format. Now, after training both these models, I loaded the trained weights into the models, and want to merge the two models by giving them the same input layer.
As of now, both these models have an InputLayer with the same input dimensions (100, 100, 3).

My thought process was that: after loading the trained weights in the 2 models, and freezing their layers, I will remove the InputLayer from both these models, and create a new model with a input as a new InputLayer, and outputs as the outputs of both these models.

However, when I tried to remove the input layer from the models using `model.pop()`, it didn't work. It kept giving me the same model. Furthermore, I am not sure that even if I am somehow able to remove the input layers of the 2 models and create a new model in the way I described above, will the trained weights be preserved in the new model or not.

I am working on Tensorflow2.
Please suggest appropriate methods of doing the above.